# date duration between two dates excluding holidays stored in my database

Tags: php

I want to calculate days excluding holidays stored in my database.
But I am getting error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function isWithinDates()

```
$holidays = array();
$get_holidays = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM holiday_list");
while ($fetch_holidays = mysqli_fetch_array($get_holidays)){
    $holidays[]=$fetch_holidays['holiday_date'];
}
echo $begin_date = $emp_leave_data['startDate'];
echo $end_date = $last_date;
$exclude = 0;

// Loop over holidays to find out whether they are in the range
foreach ($holidays as $holiday) {
    if (isWithinDates(new DateTime($holiday), $begin_date, $end_date)) {
        $exclude++;
    }
}

function isWithinDates(DateTime $date, DateTime $start, DateTime $end)
{
    return $date >= $start && $date <= $end;
}

// Get the amount of days between our start date and the end date
// and subtract the amount of days that we know to be holidays
echo $duration = $begin_date->diff($end_date)->days - $exclude + 1;
```

Comment: Looks defined to me, and when I run this I don't get that error. Is the second part `include`d from another script?

Comment: Yes, we're not seeing the whole picture here. You're probably have mismatching brackets `{..}` or something similar.

Comment: My rest codes are:- 
$last_date = date("Y-m-25");
$holidays = array('2017-08-20','2017-08-27');

Comment: OK, where is the value for `$emp_leave_data` coming from. Are you including any other files?

Comment: @mega6382 not possible to declare it outside foreach loop. because isWithinDates need $holiday as its parameter.

Comment: @mega6382 $emp_leave_data generated from $get_emp_leave_data = "SELECT * FROM emp_leave_tracker WHERE empID='".$empID."' AND endDate > '".$last_date."' AND status='Approved'";
  if($result1=mysqli_query($link, $get_emp_leave_data)){
   while($emp_leave_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    if($emp_leave_data['startDate'] > $last_date){